# MailKit retrieve Email account logo/avatar

Tags: .net, smtp, imap, mailkit, mimekit

I am using Mailkit to programmatically retrieve email messages from email accounts.
Is there a standard way using IMAP to retrieve the email account logo/avatar for example from Gmail using MailKit?
Does IMAP define avatar for email accounts?

Comment: What you're looking for is probably [BIMI](https://bimigroup.org/implementation-guide/), which you can support using IMAP, but you'll have to write somewhere between a hundred and a thousand lines of code. (I haven't done it, just looked at how much work it might be.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core IMAP protocol has no support for avatars.

What you are probably looking for is [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/) which uses an email address (or login name) as a key for looking up a globally hosted avatar.

You can query their service using an email address as a key and get back an avatar if the user has created one and uploaded it to their service.